# Regexp not making all intended replacements

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following `keyup` event handler:

```
$('#id_content').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var input = $.trim($(this).val());
    var matches = input.match(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/);
    if (matches) {
        var submatch = matches[1];
        input = input.replace(submatch, '<pre>'+submatch+'</pre>').replace(/\*\*/g,'');
    }
    $('#preview_tip').html(input);
});
```

Meaning I have a textarea, and if I insert `a **b** c **d**`, it should make the input:

```
a <pre>b</pre> c <pre>d</pre>
```

But it is only making the input:

```
a <pre>b</pre> c d
```

What am I doing wrong in my regexp?

Comment: Make that `input.match(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g)`

Comment: @L3viathan tried, didnot do it

Comment: Works for me. The **g** flag makes it match globally, so multiple matches per line are allowed. If I run it and print out `matches`, I get `["**b**", "**d**"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only manipulating one match per `matches[1]`: so it makes sense that only one match is replaced.

Try something like this instead:

```js
var input = 'a **b** c **d**';
var replacedInput = input.replace(/\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}/g, '<pre>$1</pre>');
console.log(replacedInput);
alert(replacedInput); // to make the result obvious
```

`$1` in the replacement string allows you to use the capture group `(.*?)`'s value in the replacement for each match.

Also, you can use `\*{2}` instead of `\*\*`, but that is really just a matter of preference.

To see how this approach plays out in your event handler, check out a [related JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J0e3gan/cp1fz8xv/).

Comment: it is not working if I press enter in between ``'a **\n b ** c **d**';``. how can I fix it?